# why my js doesn't read php output as json

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I'm using AngularJs and php, I've created a php file that returns Json format, but when it comes to reading it from my js file, the output is  the php code !

The server works fine with php and the php file is exectuded perfectlly and return json format but when i call it in the app the output is my php text witch meens that the php file is reeded as a text.

What should I do to make it readable as json ?

This is my anjularJs call:

```
$http.get( './templates/connect.php').success(
function(data){
  $scope.cityes=data;  
  alert($scope.cityes); 
});
```

And this is my php file:

```
$qry = mysql_query('SELECT capital from countries');
$emparray = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $emparray[] = $rows;
}
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: Does control goes in `success` function ? Did you try with `alert` or `console.log` ?

Comment: Sure your server processes php?

Comment: You should view the PHP file itself, and check for (white)spaces at the beginning or the end of the content. Make sure the json object is the only content on the page.

Comment: Assuming your php file is correct and there are no other problems with the request, use some debuging in your javascript file. Also I don't remember if $.get from jquerry automatically converts the data to json. You could try `$.getJSON('<host>', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });` or use $.ajax standard with specifying the dataType, I always use $.ajax although you write more you have more control. Cheers

Comment: The server works fine with php and the php file is exectuded perfectlly and return json format but when i call it in the app the  output is my php text witch meens that the php file is reeded as a text

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **your PHP file starts with a `<?php`** and the PHP processor is enabled in your server:

```
<?php
$qry = mysql_query('SELECT capital from countries');
$emparray = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $emparray[] = $rows;
}
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

[More about the PHP syntax and its opening/closing tags.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Be careful with Json headers and IE, well anything with IE is just.. yuck.